# how to get downloaded image in GeckoFX browser?

Tags: c#, .net, geckofx

How to get image from the page in GeckoFX browser?

I know i can simply get value of 'src' attribute and then use WebClient to donwload the file, but I need to get it from the browser, because otherwise picture will be changed on the next download.

Answer (score 2):

However you can put this code into etc context menu strip when image is right-clicked:

```
if(geckoWebBrowser1.CopyImageContents())//if image contents can be copied...
{
    System.Drawing.Image img = Clipboard.GetImage();//copy image into variable

    //here you can use a folder browser dialog to locate path manualy
    img.Save(Application.StartupPath + "tempImg.jpg");//will save image to path

    //last two lines is optional and can open same image in default image preview program
    string fak = Application.StartupPath + "tempImg.jpg";
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fak);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Geckofx 13 supports this: [Image Creator in geckofx](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-13.0/src/9ca5047ceea6/Skybound.Gecko/ImageCreator.cs)